# Type lookup or type alias references in mypy

Tags: mypy

I have a function as follows:

```py
def a():
  return b()
```

What I want is either:

```py
def a() -> ReturnType[typeof b]:
  return b()
```

or... the original example with the return type fully inferred.

I searched the mypy docs and poked inside of the `typing` module. I'm unclear if this is feasible. Let me know! Thanks

Comment: There was [some mention of this](https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8385) on the MyPy issues a few years back but Jukka's comments make it sound fairly unlikely to progress beyond the wishlist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per @motto above, this is not supported. See https://github.com/python/mypy/issues/8385